# Как в Beautiful Soup спрасить одинаковые элементы, без дочерних элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как в Bs4 спрарсить родительские элементы td без дочерних td, на каждой странице родительских элементов  может быть разное количество

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Какой то текст</td>
    <td>Какой то текст2</td>
    <td>Какой то текст3</td>
    <td>Какой то текст3</td>
    <td>
       <tbody>
          <td>Какой то текст, который не нужно парсить1</td>
          <td>Какой то текст, который не нужно парсить2</td>
          <td>Какой то текст, который не нужно парсить3</td>
       </tbody>
    </td>
    <td>Какой то текст4</td>
    <td>Какой то текст5</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться `recursive=False`

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не очень понятно какой вариант Вы ожидаете, но попробуйте вот так

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

txt = """<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Какой то текст</td>
    <td>Какой то текст2</td>
    <td>Какой то текст3</td>
    <td>Какой то текст3</td>
    <td>
       <tbody>
          <td>Какой то текст, который не нужно парсить1</td>
          <td>Какой то текст, который не нужно парсить2</td>
          <td>Какой то текст, который не нужно парсить3</td>
       </tbody>
    </td>
    <td>Какой то текст4</td>
    <td>Какой то текст5</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>"""

soup = Soup(txt, 'html.parser')

tbody = soup.find('tbody')

for elem in tbody.find_all(['tbody', 'table']):
    elem.replace_with('')


print(
    *[
        item.get_text(strip=True)
        for item in tbody.find_all('td')
        if item.get_text(strip=True)
    ],
    sep='\n'
)

#Какой то текст
#Какой то текст2
#Какой то текст3
#Какой то текст3
#Какой то текст4
#Какой то текст5
```